# Canvas Element Not Render In Proper Position

Tags: unity

I don't know what's going wrong. The `Text` and `Slider` must be on the red square area. Anyone can help to determine this bug ? Thanks

[image]

Comment: With this few information, it will be impossible to help you... The anchors or the anchoredPoint (similar to localPosition), may be wrong... You should follow the [tutorials of Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/ui/rect-transform) and read the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

Comment: Could you provide an image of the inspector when you have one of those elements selected? Also a view of the Hierarchy would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend had found it. The update is just to fast. My code is set the `Text` and `Slider` value first before I `SetActive(true)`. It's mean the canvas don't get the chance to update the position because it just too fast.

So the solution is `SetActive(true)` the canvas first, Then update the canvas position

Comment: If the issue is solved, can you mark your question as correct? This will prevent it from popping up in the front page.